# Strength/Safety of Suntour XCR Air RL-R/Budget Suspension Bikes

Tags: suspension, electric-bike

I have been riding bikes my entire life and I am now thinking of getting a new bike.

Until the past year I have been riding walmart bikes and I never really thought much about the spec.

I have gone off 4 foot drops and jumps many times on my walmart bikes without fail.

Only recently after reading some online posts did I know it was even possible for those front forks to break.

My question is how strong would a bike like this be going up and down stairs and off curbs and small drops? Keep in mind comfort is no problem to, I mean yes I would love to have nice suspension but as long as it is decent I shouldn't have a problem. I mean I am comfortable on even walmart suspension, key question for me: is this new bike going to fail in a way which will cause me to use my facebrake?

http://wheelworld.com/product/haibike-sduro-fullnine-sl-263280-1.htm

What about a hard tail like this? http://www.cynergyebikes.com/Haibike-SDuro-Hardseven-SM-ebike-p/hb_sduro_hardseven_sm_6.htm

Comment: It's impossible for any of us to tell for sure how long a BSO would last - and even if we did pull a number out of our rear jersey pocket -- say "a 20% of failure in the next six months" - it's unsure whether that'd be helpful. All you and we know is that a catastrophic failure is likely to be very painful. So I'm not sure if we can provide any satisfying answer.

Comment: As far as the electric bikes go, you should generally subtract about $800 from the cost of the bike to arrive at the cost of the frame+components. So a $2500 ebike would be the equivalent of an $1700 in terms of frame+components. So the models you provide are in the mid range. So they should do stairs and curbs fine assuming good technique and good maintenance.

Comment: I got the bike, it's awesome and can absolutely handle small drops and stairs no problem! I love this bike and this suspension way underrated IMO. When I go online they make it seem like Suntour is just garbage but it's actually nice

Answer (score 1):

Forks break. Every brand has examples of it. Its a given when people push bike past their design limits many times. Your more likely to be hit by a car or stuck by lightening.

While Suntour XCR's are a budget shock, they are a mountain bike shock used on entry level bikes sold by dealerships. A bike with XCR's is usually not what I would call a BSO. They are an XC shock, certainly not designed for landing 4 foot drops, but should handle riding down stair cases provided you are not jumping.

Suntour is a major player in entry level MTB's, and as such, is a reputable brand. They don't have the brand power of RockShox or Fox etc because they don't play in the "money is no object' space and don't sponsor world cup riders

I believe its unlikely the fork will fail catastrophically. You may damage its internals and it might wear out quicker than a more expensive shock. Worst case is likely a major crack or bend, but the fork staying in one piece.

That said, if your taking 4 foot jumps, all bets are off. A bad landing can break a frame in half on any bike, let alone an entry level XC bike.  (In the early 1990's I was landing 4 footers on fully rigid bikes, so in theory, no need for suspension. But then I was 20 something and my frontal lobe had not yet developed fully)

Comment: My reference to BSO was not to the XCR but to the bikes the OP originally had.